# How can I insert year only in date type column using php

Tags: php, date, cakephp

I am creating an edit form, in which I have  that the options are years for birthday, since I just want to change the year not the date and month. In my database, the column type is in date. I can't change the year but it is storing a default value which is 0000-00-00.

Here is the code that I a using.

```
<?php
    $years = array();
    $end = date('Y') - 101;
    $start = date('Y');
    $yearUser = date('Y',strtotime($userData['User']['birthday']));
    $counter = 0;
    $selectedYear=0;
    for($i=$start;$i>$end;$i--){
        if($yearUser == $i)
        {
            $selectedYear = $counter;
        }
        $counter++;
        array_push($years,$i);
    }
    echo $this->Form->select('birthday',array(
    'options' => $years,
    'selected' => $selectedYear
    ));       
    echo $this->Form->input('birthday',array(
       'type' => 'hidden',
       'id' => 'birthYear',
        'class' =>'user-profile-location',
    ));
?>
```

Thank you for some tips, it will be highly appreciated

Comment: Try an int field instead of date, or a char(4)

Comment: Simply use a proper data type instead of a fugly workaround: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html No other modifcations are needed then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DATE` field is always going to be a full date. You have  to specify a full date.

Obviously, you can format the output of a DATE field With:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(yourfield,"%Y-%m");
```

> As per description on this [web](https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/databases/mysql/insert-date/#Insert_a_date_in_MySQL_using_YEAR) you can use.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (yourfield) VALUE ('YEAR: Auto CURDATE()', CURDATE() )";
```

Comment: thank you .. i used the strotime function to get the year and then i used two types of input hidden and the select to get the value.

Answer (score 4):

No, You cant save only year in date column

It says in the MySQL manual that you can store partial dates

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

For that you need to change the datatype of column to **Varchar(4)** then you can easily do that...

Otherwise you have to save complete date then you can get only year by [YEAR()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-year-function.php) function in MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your column type on the database then you will have to convert the user input to a ISO date format with Y-m-d, that way you store the full date on the database then you only have to extract the year part from that column when selecting the record on the database:

TO STORE IT ON DATABASE FROM THE USER INPUT

```
$yearUser = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($userData['User']['birthday']));
```

Note that PHP will automatically put current month and day value. ie today is: 9-18, plus user selected year lets say 1983, that would be: `1983-09-18`

RETRIEVE STORED YEAR VALUE ONLY:

```
$yearUser = date('Y',Model->birthday));
```

If you do can change the data type on the database then just simply store it as an integer, since date() function is already returning an integer in that case.